# css {right:0; position:absolute;} element should not displace when browser resized

Tags: css, position

The element with this property is displaced when browser is re sized.
**What property** should i use to prevent the element getting displaced along with the browser, and still it has to be in the right end as given?

```
.cssclass
{
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/TbYz5/)

Comment: resized vertically or horizontally ?

Comment: No. eg: if my page's height is 2000px and i want an element to be set in the 1900-2000th px(always in the bottom). how can i do this? using fixed position will not help.

Comment: if bottom:0 is set and the browser is re sized the element moves along with it. how to set it always at the bottom? using fixed position will not help because the element will not be scrolled along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/q9uN9/)

html:

```
<div class="bottom_banner">HELLO</div>
```

css:

```
body{
    position:relative;
    height:2000px;
    background:navy;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.bottom_banner{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    bottom:0;
    background:red;
    margin:0;
}
```

## EDIT:

here is an example for a fixed-width page with a banner stuck on bottom right of the page: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/w57pS/)

html:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="right_banner"> Sup?</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
    background:#99cccc;
}
.content{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:white;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px;
    height:2000px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.right_banner
{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background:#cc99ff;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    color:navy;
    border:1px solid black;
    opacity:0.8;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Comment: yes. but if the element is set right:0px; its not being static like bottom:0px; does

Comment: i really dont understand you. what is the problem?

Comment: likewise can you make right banner? but it should not move along with the right end of the browser window when re sized.

Comment: i have updated my answer, is this what you needed?